# android icon on status bar

Tags: android, notifications, statusbar

I can set even after turning off and turn on the phone icon still stays?
For example, an alarm clock

i use this code:

```
  public void setNotificationToStatusBar(){
      String forwarder_start_str= getResources().getString(R.string.sms_forwarding_activated);
      String app_name=getResources().getString(R.string.app_name);
      Intent intent= new Intent(this, PrefActivitySmsForwarder.class);
      Notification n= new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher,forwarder_start_str, System.currentTimeMillis());
      n.flags=Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;
      PendingIntent pi=PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0,intent,0);
      n.setLatestEventInfo(getApplicationContext(), app_name, forwarder_start_str, pi);
      n.defaults= Notification.DEFAULT_ALL;
      nm.notify(uniqueId, n);
      finish();

  }
```

After I turn off the phone, the icon disappears but the app works

Answer (score 2):

By nature, notifications will not persist through a device reboot. You will manually need to determine when the device has been restarted and issue the notification again.

[Trying to start a service on boot on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784441/trying-to-start-a-service-on-boot-on-android)